# woods - gramatically singular or plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural

It is clear that "woods" is semantically plural, but what about gramatically? Can it be both singular and plural, as other collective nouns ? Example:

- The woods of this town contain many secrets.
- The woods of this town contains many secrets.

Comment: I think it's singular (a mass noun) but there may be exceptions.

Comment: *The woods **around** this town **contain** many secrets*.

Comment: Generally, we'd say have and not contain here. And we wouldn't say: the woods of this town. We'd say near this town, around this town, etc. or the town in these woods.

Comment: One particularly well-known example is Winnie-the-Pooh's ***Hundred Acre Woods*** - always written using the "plural" form in A. A. Milne's original text, but searching for written instances of "the hundred acre **wood / woods is / are** [blah blah]" in Google Books, I see some people feel compelled to switch it to "singular" ***wood*** to tone down the awkwardness of the apparent noun/verb "plurality clash".

Comment: See [“Woods” and then verb. Singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504956/woods-and-then-verb-singular-or-plural/505049#505049). Also, it's not at all clear that *woods* is semantically plural. The plural formation is still often used to describe a singular object. I think what you meant to say is that the word, purely on its own, is syntactically plural.

Comment: None of the answers point out that this is a British/American difference. In British English "woods" is always plural, but we can talk about "a wood".  For (at least some) Americans, "woods" is singular.

Comment: @ColinFine Woods is plural for me, almost always. Where's John? He went for a walk in the woods. Where are you going this weekend? To the woods. And I believe St. John's Wood is a district in Westminster....

Comment: The town woods harbor many secrets. "The woods of this town"" is not very idiomatic and sounds like French or Portuguese where you need the de. I have never, ever seen woods with a verb in the singular. No one says: The woods is two miles from town. Unless they have very working class speech.

Comment: And finally, wood without an s is often what Shakespeare used://Macbeth shall never vanquish'd be until Great Birnam **wood** to high Dunsinane hill
Shall come against him.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: I call "Citation needed" on "The Hundred Acre Woods". I remember it from my childhood as _The Hundred Acre Wood_, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Acre_Wood) agrees. Admittedly there are no sources cited for that article, but on the low-resolution image of Shepherd's I believe I can make out "HUNDRED ACRE WOOD".

Comment: @Lambie: yes, for me _woods_ is always plural, but I have the singular _wood_ as well. However, singular _wood_ is always definite: "I was walking in the wood" expects the hearer to know which wood, whereas "I was walking in the woods" doesn't.

Comment: @ColinFine: I stand corrected! I really thought it *was* plural in the original, but checking more carefully through Google Books I see I was completely mistaken on that one. I shall fall back on [*If you go down in the **woods** today,*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&corpus=26&content=down+to+the+woods+today%2Cdown+to+the+wood+today&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdown%20to%20the%20woods%20today%3B%2Cc0) which is almost ***never*** singular.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question should be "The woods near the town contain many secrets."

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/woods) calls "woods" a "plural noun", with the example "Shaded from the sun, the woods were cool and quiet."

[wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/woods) is more cautious: "usually in the plural, sometimes singular" and "Woods more often takes a plural verb (determiner, etc, as in these woods are) than a singular verb (as in this woods is)."

There is an interesting and apropos comment on [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131636/singular-nouns-in-plural-form):

> It gets trickier when there's an adjective. Although I can find both of these constructions in Google books, I wouldn't say a small woods (because it's plural), or some small woods (because mass nouns don't work that way; you can't say some small rice either). I'd say a small stretch of woods or a large expanse of woods. – Peter Shor

Comment: The woods can be part of a town....so, town woods works fine.